# Cron Tab as specific user and python virtual env

Tags: linux, cron, virtualenv

Wanting to run an hourly cron job as a specific user (xfeautomation) and python virtual environment. Running as a specific user, will I have to add the script location into PATH?
My current cron job looks like this:

```
0 * * * *  xfeautomation /opt/scripts/wf_venv/bin/python /opt/scripts/wf_api_linux.py 2>&l /opt/scripts/log.txt
```

Is this the correct or optimal way? TIA

Answer (score 1):

switch to that user.

`sudo su - xfeautomation`

Run

`crontab -e`

A file editor with empty file will appear. Add your job without user name there and save it.

`0 * * * *  /opt/scripts/wf_venv/bin/python /opt/scripts/wf_api_linux.py 2>&l /opt/scripts/log.txt`

Verification:

`sudo su - xfeautomation` 
`crontab -l`

OR

`sudo crontab -u  xfeautomation`

Answer (score 0):

> Running as a specific user, will I have to add the script location into PATH?

You usually don't need to modify the PATH environment variable when you're using absolute paths such as you're doing now with  `/opt/scripts/wf_venv/bin/python /opt/scripts/wf_api_linux.py 2>&l /opt/scripts/log.txt`

As sysadmin you have several options to create scheduled batch jobs that run under a different user ID:

1. As explained in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1074178/794142): **set up a personal crontab for that user**. Jobs in a personal crontab will always run under the user ID of their owner.
   Note that when you as the administrator set up  a personal crontab for another user, that user will be able to modify and delete that cron job specification, undoing your work.
2. Alternatively you can **schedule a system job from the system crontab**. The system crontab (typically `/etc/crontab` and/or drop-in files in `/etc/cron.d/`) is owned by root and can't be modified by unprivileged users. The job specification in the system crontab supports an extra field not present in personal crontab files: field #6 needs a username, such as `xfeautomation` of the user ID that will be used to execute the job.
   The syntax you posted is correct for an entry in `/etc/crontab` or a drop-in file like `/etc/cron.d/wf_api_linux`

   ```
   0 * * * *  xfeautomation /opt/scripts/wf_venv/bin/python /opt/scripts/wf_api_linux.py 2>&l /opt/scripts/log.txt
   ```

Since you're logging all output and errors not a concern, but normally cron will email standard output and errors to root when you set up a system crontab and directly to the user when using a personal crontab.

As far as I know effectively both methods result in the same conditions for the job and aside from the concerns about ownership of the job spec and emails, they are equivalent.